# A/C air handler in Attic duct runs

Tags: air-conditioning, ducts, cooling, pressure

I’ve noticed that all of my ducts in the house have great air flow where I can easily hear the air flowing from the vent. There is one room that doesn’t have good pressure and I can tell the room feels warmer than the others. I’ve checked for kinks in the line and even had the company that installed the new unit 4 yrs ago come check for any leaks or if there were any dampeners on the line. So I noticed that the duct that runs to that room comes off the trunk right next to an below a duct that runs to my bedroom. My bedroom blows extremely well and if I close my vent I get good flow back to that room I have an issue with. So I am assuming it is because the line is too close to another? Here’s a photo. They are a good reputable company I’m not sure if how they ran these next to one another is proper or something they should’ve known not to do.  [image]

Comment: I will note that the bigger duct, farther from camera, seems to be held up with some thinish wire of some sort. While there's nothing inherently wrong with that, the duct could, over time, collapse along that line. If it's actually wide, flexible plastic duct hangar, then it should be OK. My HVAC guys (30 years ago) ran a 6" trunk line and hung it with the same strapping as the 16" return line. Over time, the 6" duct slipped down and got crushed by the 16" line, completely cutting off flow to that room.

Comment: I noticed that too. All other ducts are done proper with the right strapping not sure why they did that line like that. Also the one room I have an issue with looks like it has an elbow to it an the flex line is running on the floor boards then it goes up to the elbow with no straps and it looked like it had a little kink in it. After doing some reading I had got the pepper strapping and I put some on there which did help the flow a bit more but I know it’s still not the best Because it’s next to the line for my bedroom. I also put my iPhone through the register to check for kinks at the elbow

Answer (score 1):

The 7" duct appears to be smaller than the one going to your bedroom and it looks longer which would be why your bedroom is getting more air, path of least resistance. The arrangement out of the trunk line, plenum,  looks normal. You can try adjusting, closing, the registers in the other rooms just a bit to increase the air flow into the room in question. This is a fairly common problem with duct runs at the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, yes I just closed my vent slightly and I’m already noticing the difference in my sons room. I have an ecobee sensor in there and it’s registering same as the others now. Is it normal to feel a bit of cold air leak from the neck where the duct meets the trunk where the aluminum tape is used? I have to patch up where the technician pulled some off to check for any dampeners, he should’ve re-taped what he peeled back.

Comment: It's not normal to feel cool air leaking in the attic.... that air should be in a room so you'll want to fix it with some foil tape from your home store.

Comment: Thanks. Also would it be better if I were to remove that longer duct from where it is and connect it elsewhere on the trunk and that would give it better airflow? Instead of it being right beside another.

Comment: If the rooms are equal in temperature, don't mess with it.  I'm not sure how the rest of the trunk line goes but there must be a reason the installers didn't install that 7" duct  further down in the picture and make that run shorter. I'd stick with adjusting the registers

Comment: They say when you close registers that you create a back pressure an can damage the air handler? Is that true? I mean I don’t have it completely closed but I can obviously hear the air blowing harder through the register.

Comment: If you closed a number of them, yes, you could create back pressure but what your doing is redirecting air at the end of a run from your vent to the other room. That's why the registers have those adjustable vents.

Comment: Thanks. Also what does it mean when I hear the air in my vent kinda cut out but then comes back s Econ’s or two at higher velocity it sounds like?

Comment: A popular ECON setting runs the blower every ten minutes at low speed to circulate and check the air temp.  When the air temp is above the thermostat setting, it kicks in the compressor and switches the fan to HI.

Comment: @Envieddesigns, if you'll take the [tour], you'll note the proper way of saying "thanks".